# How to prevent RichTextBox to change alignment automatically?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, alignment, richtextbox

I am programming a text editor and I use richtextboxes.
In one of the richtextboxes I need the text aligned to the right, so I use:

```
RTB.SelectAll()
RTB.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right
RTB.DeselectAll()
```

And it's ok, the text is horizontally aligned to the right. The problem is when I do any change (for example, pasting some text or any other change) all the text in that RichTextBox gets automatically aligned to the left again (originally it was left aligned).

What should I modify to prevent the text to align again to the left after I have applied right alignment?

Thanks.

Comment: You could set the the RTB to Right to Left = Yes.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Sorry for the basic questions.